# Liquibase - Optional diff parameters not working

Tags: liquibase

Platform: Windows, against DB2-for-i

`liquibase update`, `liquibase status`, and `liquibase rollback` are all working.

When I attempt to limit the `diff` command (or the `diffChangeLog` command) by using ANY of the optional diff parameters (`--schemas`, --`includeObjects`, etc) I get the following:

```
> liquibase.bat 
  --url=jdbc:as400://dbhost1/dbname 
  --username=user 
  --password=password 
  --changeLogFile=.\db2.changelog.xml 
  diffChangeLog 
  --schemas=MYSCHEMA 
  --referenceUrl=jdbc:as400://dbhost2/dbname 
  --referenceUsername=user 
  --referencePassword=password

Unexpected error running Liquibase: Unknown option: 'schemas'
liquibase.exception.CommandLineParsingException: Unknown option: 'schemas'
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.parseOptionArgument(Main.java:818)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.parseOptions(Main.java:764)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:177)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:129)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this, but I think you just need to re-order things and put the options before the command.

```
liquibase.bat 
  --url=jdbc:as400://dbhost1/dbname 
  --username=user 
  --password=password 
  --changeLogFile=.\db2.changelog.xml 
  --schemas=MYSCHEMA 
  --referenceUrl=jdbc:as400://dbhost2/dbname 
  --referenceUsername=user 
  --referencePassword=password
  diffChangeLog
```

Comment: The `--reference*` parameters definitely have to follow `diffChangeLog` (I get an error regarding those if they come before. I have tried `--schemas` both before and after the `diffChangeLog` command but I get the same error message.